# Intel AMT gives 401 Unauthorized when trying to login

Tags: login, amt, intel

I'm trying to get AMT working on a brand new DQ77KB motherboard. I've followed [this setup guide](http://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments/manualsetupandconfigurationfromrelease60.htm) but I can't login to the web interface (http://[IP]:16992) or though the [KVMControlApplication.exe](http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2011/10/using-intel-amts-vnc-server/). Both approaches gives me a *401 Unauthorized*. I'm using *admin* as the username, I've tried a lot of different passwords containing different special letters, I've reset the AMT with a jumper on the MEBx header on the motherboard to be sure every was reset and I'm an Intel AMT noob :-)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maby the issue is as simple as the special letters are not what I think they are. The password input is masked and I'm using a non english keyboard. I'll look in to this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A total PEBKAC :-)

It was indeed a keyboard layout issue. One can use the *hostname* input as a scratchpad if running in to issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should setup Intel AMT first. Enter MEBx and press Activate Network Access.
2. You should login to the web from another host (not AMT-computer to control). Login as admin and password which you set in MEBx.